# Why does Xcode create two targets for watch app?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm new to WatchKit and I want to develop a Watch extension for my existing iOS app. I did develop a Share Extension before in the same project, so I know a bit about how extension targets are embedded into the app.

However, when I added a Watch app target using default settings, it created two targets, `Watch` and `Watch Extension`. I have trouble understanding the purpose of having both. `Watch` appears to have non-model content (e.g. assets, storyboard) by default and `Watch Extension` appears to have my actual code (e.g. interface controllers). Why aren't they together by default? What is the purpose of splitting them, as they will both run together on the Watch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Apple Watch first came out, the "Extension", ran on the phone and the "App", which contained the UI, ran on the watch. With the release of Watch OS 2, both run natively on the watch, but the targets continue to be separated. Hopefully soon we'll be able to have one target

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say that they'd always need to be separate targets in terms of build dependencies, they *do* need to be distinct in terms of packaging, because the app and extension *aren't* always run together.

Similar to iOS, the `.watchkitapp.watchkitextension` bundle is a distinct component of the `.watchkitapp` package. Although the watch app *does* require the app extension, it's possible for an app extension to run in the background without its app having been launched.  The watch might even be showing a completely different app in the foreground.

As an example, if an app extension included a complication which was shown on the watch face, that extension would receive a request from `ClockKit` to wake up.  Its complication controller gets instantiated (based on information in the extension's property list) to update the complication server. This would all happen independent of the watch app. The watch app itself wouldn't be launched, unless the user happened to tap on that particular watch face complication.